# Protect all worksheets in a folder with parameters

Tags: vba, excel, directory

I have the following code which is designed to protect each sheet in a particular folder on my desktop with certain parameters such as allowing the sorting of rows, sorting, and filtering.

My problem is that the code doesn't run at all. I gathered bits and pieces of code from this website and Exceltips to customize it for what I want to accomplish.

```
Sub ProtectAllSheets()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim myPassword As String
    Dim wBk As Workbook
    Dim sFileSpec As String
    Dim sPathSpec As String
    Dim sFoundFile As String
    myPassword = "random"
    sPathSpec = "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Folder"
    sFileSpec = "*.xlsx"
    sFoundFile = Dir(sPathSpec & sFileSpec)
    Do While sFoundFile = ""
        Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sPathSpec & sFoundFile)
        With wBk
            For Each sh In wBk.Worksheets
                sh.Protect Password:=myPassword, AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
            Next sh
            Application.DisplayAlerts = False
            wBk.SaveAs Filename:=.FullName
            Application.DisplayAlerts = True
        End With
        Set wBk = Nothing
        Workbooks(sFoundFile).Close 
        sFoundFile = Dir
    Loop
End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong to prevent this code from running?

Comment: Is not running at all or is running and raising an error? My first impression is that `Workbooks.Open(sPathSpec & sFoundFile)` should be `Workbooks.Open(sPathSpec & "\" & sFoundFile)`

Comment: Yep, or just have `sPathSpec = "C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Folder\"`

Comment: When I try this method it gives me error 1004 "We couldn't find C:\Users\Name\Desktop\Folder\."

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are copying code from somewhere. A few issues you have:

1. With your use of `sPathSpec`, you need to have `\` at the end
2. Make sure the folder on Desktop does exist, if different change the code
3. Use Environment variables when possible `Environ("USERPROFILE")` gives you the Profile path of the user who runs this macro
4. Your `Do-Loop` is wrong! You should **stop until no files found** instead of **loop when nothing is found**
5. You should ensure the file is opened successfully before changing it
6. The reason of using `With wBk`...

I have altered some lines to improve performance and a `Debug` line to list all the files that are saved.

So you should try this:

```
Sub ProtectAllSheets()
    Const myPassword = "random"
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim wBk As Workbook
    Dim sFileSpec As String
    Dim sPathSpec As String
    Dim sFoundFile As String

    sPathSpec = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\Folder\"
    sFileSpec = "*.xlsx"
    sFoundFile = Dir(sPathSpec & sFileSpec)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Do Until sFoundFile = ""
        Set wBk = Workbooks.Open(sPathSpec & sFoundFile)
        If Not wBk Is Nothing Then
            With wBk
                For Each sh In .Worksheets
                    sh.Protect Password:=myPassword, AllowInsertingRows:=True, AllowDeletingRows:=True, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True
                Next sh
                .Save
                Debug.Print "Saved: " & .FullName
                .Close
            End With
            Set wBk = Nothing
        End If
        sFoundFile = Dir
    Loop
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```